# How to send curl upload progress to ajax to be displayed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, progress-bar

What I am trying to do is upload the file/files information to `upload.php` using ajax, then uploading the same information again to a remote server by curl to `remoteUpload.php`. Finally in `remoteUpload.php` file I perform the actual upload of the file/files.

When doing the first step -> upload the file/files information to `upload.php` I display a progress bar of this step using ajax.

But the when doing the second step -> upload the same information again to remote server using curl to `remoteUpload.php` the progress bar is not displayed, and this is my problem.

[image]

**How to display the progress bar for second step by ajax ?**

**Javascript:**

```
var upload_btn = document.getElementById('upload_file');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

upload_btn.onclick = function () {
    var uploadInput = document.getElementsByName('file[]')[0];
    if (uploadInput.files.length > 0) {
        console.clear();
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var inputFileData = formData(uploadInput);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                result.innerHTML = json.text;
            }
        };
        ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            result.innerHTML = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + "%";
        });
        ajax.open("post", "upload.php");
        ajax.send(inputFileData);
    }
};

function formData(inputFileObj) {
    var formData = new FormData;
    var inputFile = inputFileObj.files;
    if (inputFile.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < inputFile.length; i++) {
            formData.append(inputFileObj.name, inputFile[i]);
        }
    }
    return formData;
}
```

**PHP: (upload.php)**

```
function progressCallback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) {
    static $last; 
    $progress = @round($ulnow / $ultotal * 100);
    if($last < $progress) echo json_encode(array('text' => $progress));
    flush();
    $last = $progress;
}

if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' && !empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpFileName) {
        if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$index] > 0) {
            $text = "A file did not uploaded correctly.";
            return false;
        }

        $ch = curl_init("http://serverfiles/remoteUpload.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressCallback');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@' . $tmpFileName));
        $text = curl_exec($ch);  
    }
}
echo json_encode(array('text' => $text));
exit;
```

**PHP: (remoteUpload.php)**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], "files/" . $_FILES['fileupload']['name']))
    echo "The file has been uploaded.";
else
    echo "error";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save in `progressCallback()` to `$_SESSION` your `$progress` and from js side after "first step" upland complete run `setIntevral(/*ajax*/)` make `ajax` requests to server get `$_SESSION['progress]` and display second progress bar(or load first progress barr till 50% and continue load second 50%) in your form and when it complete call `clearInterval()`

---

**DETAILED ANSWER**

**Explanation:** we will count progress in following logic. If we have uploaded 5 files at once (as in your case seems uploaded was multi file) then we will divide `100%` by `5` and will increase by `25%` progress during one file curl submit, for this you need following 5 modifications

**1)** call somewhere above `session_start()` in your `upload.php` if it not done

**2)** save to session total files count and current processing file index

```
// Saveing total amount of uploaded files
$_SESSION['UP_total_count'] = count($_FILES['file']);    
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpFileName) {
    ...
    // Saving current index of uploaded file
    $_SESSION['UP_current_index'] = ($index+1);//+1 as it starts from 0
}
```

**3)** save in `progressCallback` function current progress number in `0-100` format

```
function progressCallback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) { 
    ...
    $_SESSION['UP_current_progress'] = $progress;
}
```

**4)** create new `getUploadProgress.php` and return json encoded progress infromation from session

```
session_start();
echo json_encode( array(
   'total_count' => $_SESSION['UP_total_count'],
   'current_index' => $_SESSION['UP_current_index'],
   'current_progress' => $_SESSION['UP_current_progress'],
) );
```

**5)** add in your `ajax.onreadystatechange` `setInteval` function call, and define in your js global variable `progressSetInterval`

```
....
var progressSetInterval = null;// Global

ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            ...
            progressSetInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "getUploadProgress.php",
                   success: function(data){

                       // Calculating progress based on 100 25 logic explained above
                       var progressPart = 100 / data['total_count'];
                       var currProgress = 
                           (data['total_count'] - data['current_index']) * progressPart;

                       currProgress += (progressPart/100) * data['current_progress'];

                       // You can display progress somehow, apped to div or show prgoress...
                       console.log( "Second progress: " + currProgress);

                       // if currProgress is 100% removing setinterval
                       if( currProgress >= 100 ){
                           clearInterval( progressSetInterval );
                       }
                   },
                   dataType: 'json'
               });
            }, 1000);
        }
};
```

**NOTE:** during usage of this example code of course there will be needed additional `rounds`, `JS/PHP functions` addition, variable adjustments or some logical adjustments for more effectiveness, but basically this is logic of one option which you can use

Comment: Thank you, but how to apply your words on my code ?

Comment: ok i have tried as match as possible explain it on basic example, check code after **DETAILED ANSWER**

Comment: Unfortunately, the progress does not appear but it waiting until it finish and then prints directly 100%.

Comment: Actually from this point i can't help you, neither you should update your question with new codes or create php fiddle, neither you should debug it make dumps on different places in php and js to see what is in session what you get in js what progress calculate js etc ... or you can put logging in php files(to not break upload flow with dump and exit) for example you can put in `progressCallback` this loging `file_put_content("PATH/progress.log", json_encode($progress)."\n", FILE_APPEND);`